# get_field() of ACF plugin wordpress assign to javascript value

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Im having a problem of assigning data of get_field() to a javascript variable

```
    <?php $event_message = get_field('event_message');?>
    <script> 
     var event_message = '<?php echo $event_message; ?>';
     console.log(event_message);
    </script>
```

it gave me empty value. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine. However, be sure to be inside the Wordpress loop or else you would have to pass the $post_id parameter to your [get_field()](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) call, like this :

```
<?php $event_message = get_field('event_message', $post_id); ?>
```

If that doesn't do the trick, we're gonna need more code to find what's wrong !

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just assign the Javascript variable directly from the ACF field. So try changing your code to:

```
  <script>
    var event_message = '<?php the_field("event_message"); ?>';
    console.log(event_message);
  </script>
```

That should work, hopefully!